# Question about Spectral Clustering equation in ESL

Tags: machine-learning, self-study

I am wondering about equation 14.64 in the book Elements of Statistical Learning. It is not really about the understanding of the equation. [Here](http://statweb.stanford.edu/~tibs/book/chap13.ps) is a link of the chapter. It is in the section on spectral clustering.

The graph Laplacian is defined by

$L = G - W$

where:
$
\begin{aligned}
W &: \text{adjacency matrix, } \{w_{ii'}\} \\
G &: \text{diagonal "degree" matrix with elements } g_{i} = \sum_{i'}w_{ii'}  
\end{aligned}
$

and in Eq. 14.64 we have:

$
\begin{aligned}
f^{T}Lf &= \sum_{i=1}^{N}g_{i}f_{i}^{2} - \sum_{i=1}^{N}\sum_{i'=1}^{N}f_{i}f_{i'}w_{ii'} \\
&= \frac{1}{2}\sum_{i=1}^{N}\sum_{i'=1}^{N}w_{ii'}(f_{i}-f_{i'})^{2}
\end{aligned}$

Where $f$ is any vector.

**My question:**
When we expand the square in the last expression, where does the $f_{i'}^{2}$ go?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The $f_{i′}^2$ disappears because of the diagonality of $G$ and some manipulation of sums. Hopefully a more explicit manipulation of the sums makes it clearer:
$$
f^T Lf  = f^T Gf − f^T W f \\
 =\sum^n_{i=1} g_i f_i^2 − \sum^n_{i=1} \sum^n_{i'=1} f_i f_{i'} w_{ii'} \\
 =
\frac{1}{2} \sum^n_{i=1} g_i f_i^2 − \sum^n_{i=1} \sum^n_{i'=1} f_i f_{i'} w_{ii'} + \frac{1}{2}\sum^n_{i'=1} g_{i'} f_{i'}^2 \\
=
\frac{1}{2} \left(
 \sum^n_{i=1} g_{i} f_i^2 
− 2 \sum^n_{i=1} \sum^n_{i'=1} f_i f_{i'} w_{ii'} 
+  \sum^n_{i'=1} g_{i'} f_{i'}^2 
\right) \\
=
\frac{1}{2} \left(
 \sum^n_{i=1} \sum^n_{i'=1} w_{ii'} f_i^2 
− 2 \sum^n_{i=1} \sum^n_{i'=1} f_i f_{i'} w_{ii'} 
+ \sum^n_{i=1}  \sum^n_{i'=1} w_{ii'} f_{i'}^2 
\right) \text{ (from the definition of }g_i )\\
=
\frac{1}{2} 
 \sum^n_{i=1} \sum^n_{i'=1} \left( w_{ii'} f_i^2 
− 2f_i f_{i'} w_{ii'} 
+ w_{ii'} f_{i'}^2 \right)
 \\
=
\frac{1}{2}
\sum^n_{i=1}\sum^n_{i'=1}
w_{ii'} (f_i − f_{i'}) ^2
$$